# Где в Google Analytics скачать код для установки на свой сайт?

Tags: php, html

Зарегистрировался на сайте гугла аналитикса, давно там не был, другой интерфейс. Завел там свой сайт, но не смог найти, где можно скачать код для установки на свой сайт, подскажите, пожалуйста, где это можно будет сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Слева вверху ссылка **Администратор** далее находим ссылку **Код отслеживания** далее нахоим ссылку **Стандартный** - копируем код.

**UPD**

В коде после строки

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

можно дописать

```
setTimeout('_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'NoBounce\', \'Over 10 seconds\'])',10000);
```

для уменьшения показателя отказов.

Answer (score 0):

Код поумолчанию для всех страниц стандарный

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try{ 
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxxx-x");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {} 
</script>
```

только в место gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxxx-x")
xxxx надо поставить данные своего аккауннта